# Suppress Specific IP Warnings in Modelsim

Tags: tcl, suppress-warnings, modelsim

A Vivado IP is generating an inordinate amount of Modelsim warnings which are making it difficult to assess the simulation for warnings I actually care about.

I see from the Modelsim command [documentation](http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/134097-modelsim-command-reference-manual-v10-3a) that in order to suppress a warning I need to include the parameter `-suppress` and then the warning numbers. My current implementation is as follows...

```
vsim -voptargs=+acc \
-L work \
-L xil_defaultlib \
-L secureip \
-L simprims_ver \
-L unifast_ver \
-L unimacro_ver \
-L unisims_ver \
-L xpm \
-L fifo_generator_v13_1_1 \
-L blk_mem_gen_v8_3_3 \
work.blr_tb xil_defaultlib.glbl -l sv_sim.log -suppress 3015,3017,3722
```

This code snippet works but I am afraid that this will suppress warnings that are created by problems with my own rtl. Is there a way of suppressing specific warnings of an IP?

For reference the warnings are all from the Vivado MIG IP and look something like this...

```
# ** Warning: (vsim-3017) ../../ip/xc7k160t2ffg676-2/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/phy/mig_7series_v4_0_ddr_mc_phy_wrapper.v(1260): [TFMPC] - Too few port connections. Expected 9, found 8.
#    Time: 0 fs  Iteration: 0  Instance: /blr_tb/blr_sbk_top_i/ddr3_balor_i/u_mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/u_mig_ddr3_64bit_32G_mig/u_memc_ui_top_std/mem_intfc0/ddr_phy_top0/u_ddr_mc_phy_wrapper/gen_dqs_iobuf_HP/gen_dqs_iobuf[0]/gen_dqs_diff/u_iobuf_dqs File: C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/data/verilog/src/unisims/IOBUFDS_DIFF_OUT_DCIEN.v
```

The MIG is compiled with the following command...

```
vlog  -work xil_defaultlib -incr \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G_mig_sim.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/clocking/*.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/controller/*.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/ecc/*.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/ip_top/*.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/phy/*.v" \
"$SBK_IP_DIR/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/mig_ddr3_64bit_32G/user_design/rtl/ui/*.v"
```

Comment: This inquire is similar to this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275016/suppress-specific-ip-warnings-in-modelsim